# Find orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, orthogonal-matrices

> Let $A$ and $B$ be given matrices of the same size. Let $Q$ be an orthogonal matrix for which $$Q^TBA^T = (BA^T)^TQ$$ Find and expression for $Q$ through $A$ and $B$.

Comment: $Q$ may be not unique, such $Q$ exist if you take $Q$ of the polar decomposition of $BA^T$

Comment: @ToniMhax can you explain it? I'm not that good in linear algebra.

Comment: $BA^T=Q|BA^T|$ so $Q^TBA^T=(BA^T)^TQ=|BA^T|$

Comment: This expression gives  condition that $C=Q^TBA^T$ is a symmetric matrix. For any symmetric matrix $C$ it holds.